# Selenium Java - how to store a variable in web element path in order to loop through multiple elements

Tags: java, selenium, loops, variables, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to loop through multiple web elements with Selenium java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#matchListWithMessages > div.messageList > a:nth-child(5)")).click();

}
```

However these web elements have different nth-child values, therefore I need to make a cssselector path like a variable, for example, i'm trying change a nth child number with a variable i of my loop, so it would go through all web elements one by one, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#matchListWithMessages > div.messageList > a:nth-child(i)")).click();

}
```

But since the code inside the brackets are String, it reads i like a String and not like a variable. Is there any way to make it right, that my loop would read i as a variable and go through all web elements one by one?

Comment: You could create a class, which instantiate the selector within the constructor.
And depending on the nth-child you need to access, just pass the value to the constructor of the class, which could return you a new element.

Let me know if you managed to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the following syntax:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    String selector = String.format("#matchListWithMessages > div.messageList > a:nth-child(%d)", i);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To strictly solve your problem. You can use below piece of code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
String csspath = "#matchListWithMessages > div.messageList > a:nth-child("+i+")";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(csspath )).click();

}
```

Also please note in your code you have used **driver.findElements** instead of **driver.findElement**. As former returns a list of web-element and click method won't work on list type, however later will return a web-element type object and you will be able to click it. See below for more information on same:
[https://www.browserstack.com/guide/findelement-in-selenium][1]

Also, Issues with your technique is that if there are less than 100 elements your code will fail or it will click only 100 if there are more. A more suitable solution will be to get a common locator available for your elements. Then we can use driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(locator))  to get list of all such elements and then loop through list to click all of them.
This way you no need to worry how many such elements are there in the page.
[1]: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/findelement-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Insert all elements in to List and for loop it to get each element.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class=matchListWithMessages] div a)"));

for(WebElement row : list) {
     row.click();
}
```